# How to create a cube from two united planes?

Tags: modeling, mesh, extrude

I just started with Blender

[image: doubt]

This image is a left view from a model made from extruded cubes. Normally, when I extrude a cube from its face, 4 new vertices are created and the other 4 are already existent.

How should I proceed if I only want to create 2 new vertices and use 6 already existent ones, that is, use 2 faces to extrude a cube?

Comment: There are a few ways to do this, I'd recommend looking into the different types of snapping in blender (`Snap to Selected` especially)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of many ways to achieve an extrusion-like result if one face is already in place:

- select the two open edges in edge-selection mode
   
  [image: edges to select]
- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>: snap 'Cursor to Selected'
   
  [image: Shift + S menu, entry 'Cursor to Selected']
- set pivot mode to '3D Cursor'
   
  [image: '3D Cursor' in pivot mode menu]
- select 'hinge' edge at the bottom
   
  [image: edge to select]
- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to duplicate, <kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>-</kbd>, <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd> to mirror around 3D Cursor
   
  [image: edge position after negative scaling has been applied]
- Fill the result by selecting pairs of edges and pressing <kbd>F</kbd>
   
  [image: final result]

Comment: I use a notebook in which I don't have the Return button nor a numerical keyboard.

Comment: @Filipe Toyoshima: Sorry, I should have written 'Enter' (fixed above). I don't think there's a difference between the two here. Or use the left mouse button, that works as well.

Comment: Another way could be F2 addon